# Representation theorem for multivariate homogeneous linear recurrences on Z^d?

Tags: generating-functions, recurrences

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfy a homogeneous linear recurrence for some coefficients $a_\Delta \in \mathbb{C}$,

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^d. \quad \sum_{\Delta \in B_k(0)}a_\Delta f(x+\Delta) = 0$$

where $B_k(0)$ is the radius-$k$ ball around 0 in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, using e.g. Manhattan distance.

Define the characteristic function to be $$p(z_1, \dots, z_d) = \sum_{\Delta \in B_k(0)}a_\Delta \prod_{i=1}^dz_i^{\Delta_i}$$

If $(r_1, \dots, r_d) \in \mathbb{C}^d$ is a root of $p$, then $f(x_1, \dots, x_d) = {r_1}^{x_1} \cdots r_d^{x_d}$ is a solution to the recurrence. And the solution space is closed under linear combinations of these functions.

To what extent is it true or false that every solution $f$ can be represented as a "mixture" of these solutions? The roots of $p$ can be an arbitrary variety in $\mathbb{C}^d$ so I am not sure what a formal statement would be. (In the $d=1$ case there are other solutions when $p$ has multiple roots but I am happy to ignore that and any similar phenomena in the multivariate case for now.)